# editfield weird height

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-editfield

In my application i have 2 types of editfields. One of them behaves like single line editfield, the other behaves like multi-line editfield (editarea). In this screen i have one header, one editfield and one editarea. When i enter some text to `editfield`, it clips the text and cursor. But, when i enter some text to `editarea` which includes a tailed character(y,g,q,p) `editarea`s height is changing and `editfield`act normal. If i dont enter tailed characters stuation does not change.

Here is my editarea class:

```
public class EditAreaField extends HorizontalFieldManager{
    private net.rim.device.api.ui.component.EditField editArea;
    public EditAreaField (){
         // some code;
         editArea.setPadding(25, 10, 0, 10);    
    }
    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        int height = Math.max(editArea.getHeight(), textFont.getHeight());
        return height  + editArea.getPaddingTop();
    }
}
```

label1 -> editfield

label2 -> editarea

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you please explain briefly?

Comment: well i did explain in the question actually. In the left image you can see, there is a clipping problem half of the cursor is over the first character, half of it is at the last character. If you type some character tailed the clipping error is no more.

Comment: can you please come here we will discuss more about this http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-and-java

Answer (score 1):

this is because you are making the size to change by using

```
    int height = Math.max(editArea.getHeight(), textFont.getHeight());
```

instead of this try to give some fixed height. for example

```
    height= Graphics.getScreenHeight()/5;
```

or you can also use setExtent inside the sublayout method of the manager

```
     protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
            {
                layoutChild(_editField, _editField.getPreferredWidth(), _editField.getPreferredHeight());
                setPositionChild(_editField, xpos,ypos);
                setExtent(preferredHeight,preferredWidth);
            }
```

I think it will work.
Please let me know

Comment: editfield is fixed size but editarea should not be fixed because we dont know how many characters will user enter. Additionally i set extent inside the sublayout method by overriding it as you said. it is weird editarea's height is 38 when initialized, when user put tailed characters it is changing to 39. There is the problem i think.

Answer (score 1):

About the cursor painting - you did override `drawFocus` or/and `onFocus` or/and `onUnfocus` and don't repaint properly sometime.

Comment: i overrode onFocus and onUnfocus. the custom component that i added the same screen in the images are behaving differently. If there is a problem on left image, the problem has to remain at the right image. the source of the problem is the editarea component i think but i am not able to solve it.